# OOC: What is the difference between ToList() and casting to List<T> in .NET?

Tags: c#, collections, casting

OOC: Out Of Curiosity

So, as a little exercise and for the sake of learning, I decided to check if I was able to implement a very basic recursive function that would return a `List<int>`, but with the following restrictions:

1- The result should be returned by the function itself (as opposed to passed as an argument to a `void` function).

2 - No local "named" variables declared in the function's body.

I came up with the solution below (BTW: can this be improved in any way?)

While doing this, I learnt that `ToList()` is not the same thing as casting to `List<T>` (see example below) - Anyone out there who can explain what happens under the hood and what the difference between the two is?

Thanks!

PS - I'm using version 4.0 (in case it matters).

EDIT: the runtime error is `Unable to cast object of type '<ConcatIterator>d__71'1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]'`

```
public static List<int> SomeIntegers(int min, int max)
{
    //assume max >= min for simplicity  
    if (min == max)
        return new List<int>() { min };

    // runtime error 
    //return (List<int>)(SomeIntegers(min, max - 1).Concat(new List<int>() { max }));   

    //works
    return (SomeIntegers(min, max - 1).Concat(new List<int>() { max })).ToList(); 
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ToList()` is not the same as (casting) to List.

`ToList()` takes any `IEnumerable` (Lists, Arrays, Dictionaries, Sets, etc) and turns it into a `List`.

Casting to `List` takes an object that is already a list of some sort, and labels it as a list. example:

```
// fail -- arrays are not lists
var not_a_list = (List<int>)int[];
// success: arrays *are* IEnumerable, so you can convert them to a list.
var list_from_array = new [] { 1,2,3,4,5 }.ToList();
// success: WorkflowRoleCollection derives from List<WorkflowRole>
var derived_from_list = (List<WorkflowRole>) new WorkflowRoleCollection();
```

In your case, `Concat()` returns an `IEnumerable`, and not a `List`. Remember that it has to support generators (which are lazy-evaluated), so it doesn't make sense for it to be anything like a list underneath.

Btw, have you taken a look at the built-in function `Enumerable.Range` ?

Answer (score 6):

- Casting only works if you actually have a `List<T>`, something derived from `List<T>`, or something with a valid type conversion to `List<T>`, otherwise it fails with an `InvalidCastException`. `ToList()` works on any IEnumerable.
- `ToList()` always creates a new copy of the list even if you already have a list. Casting something to `List<T>` typically does not produce a copy of the list - it just gives you a new compile-time type for the same object.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, the best way to generate a list of integers is:

```
Enumerable.Range(min, length);
```

or

```
Enumerable.Range(min, max-min+1);
```

But that doesn't help you learn, so kudos to you!  :)

Comment: Thanks, I just checked this; so it seems that we don't get an `Enumerable.Range(min, max, step)` or `Enumerable.Range(min, max, x => x*x)`, right?

Comment: Not directly, but you could certainly do something like `Enumerable.Range(min, length).Where(x => (x-min)%step==0)` and `Enumerable.Range(min, length).Select(x => x*x);` to get the equivalent of those

Comment: Also note that the second parameter on Enumerable.Range is LENGTH, not MAX