# Difference between as List<> vs ToList()

Tags: c#

I have a collection of strings as an Enumerable (for the example let's say its the result of some linq query on a collection).

```
IEnumerable<string> myStrings;
```

What's the difference between the following

a.

```
result = myStrings as List<string>;
```

b.

```
result = myStrings.ToList();
```

Is one more efficient than the other? Does option b change myStrings itself?

Comment: The first one is a cast (and may return `null`) the other is a method call that is guaranteed to return a `List<string>` (or throw an `ArgumentNullException`)

Comment: Your answer may be in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107115/ooc-what-is-the-difference-between-tolist-and-casting-to-listt-in-net

Comment: Option a) will fail on most `IEnumerable`s. Option b) will only fail when `myStrings` is `null`.  'efficient' will amost never be the deciding factor.

Comment: It's not a matter of efficiency, it's a matter of whether `myStrings` is already a `List` or not.

Answer (score 3):

Option a - `result=myStrings as List<string>` is a safe way to typecast and know whether a given type contains `List<string>` internally, there's no extra memory allocation, since it's typecasting it can be be done on any type / object. If the typecasting fails then result is `null`, no exception, which might come if you try `(List<string>) myStrings` instead.

Infact even better approach - `is` operator, `myStrings is List<string> result` (Called as Pattern matching is expressions) which provides boolean result and if true, it leads to valid value inside result variable (`is` operator is there for quite sometime, but using variable `result` for pattern matching which spans beyond the if loop and can be used in the logic thereafter is a C# 7.1 feature

Compared to this:

Option b - `result=myStrings.ToList()` is extension method call on a `IEnumerable<T>`, which allocates and creates new `List<T>` data structure. This is always an extra allocation of memory. Following is the source code for the `Enumerable.ToList()` call, [link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e276d6892241255b)

```
 public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
            if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            return new List<TSource>(source);
        }
```

Comment: "This is always an extra allocation of memory" - good point. I never checked this but I always assumed that `ToList` would check if `source` is already a list and just return it.

Comment: As the code suggest it always does `new List<T>`, so that the caller can work with new memory without worry about making modification to the original source. If we need existing collection, It needs typecasting, which is a good optimization step for large collections

Comment: Libraries like `Dapper` offer `AsList`, which first try to type cast and then to `ToList`, if type casting fails.

Answer (score 1):

`ToList()` is a method and creates new object of `List<T>`. That method require elements in the collection to be correct type.

Method `ToList` iterates over the collection to create **new** list, so it's slower than just casting, but safer and more generic.

Because the method creates new list, changes to original collections are not reflected in the list.

`as List<T>` casts the object on that List. That means collection must either be a `List` or inherit from it.

Casting can sometimes result in `null` when the object is not possible to cast on `List<T>`

Because casting of object still holds the reference, changes to original collection are reflected in the list.

---

More information:

`ToList()`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__

`as`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as

Answer (score 0):

`ToList` will create a new list but in your case, since you are referencing a reference type (string), then the new list will contain references to the same objects as the original list.

**Updating the myStrings property of an object referenced in the new list will also affect the equivalent object in the original list.**

So there is no immediate difference between the two.

that answers your question to whether option b change myStrings itself.

regarding the performance, yes, there will be. As referenced in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516462/is-there-a-performance-impact-when-calling-tolist):

> Yes, [`IEnumerable<T>.ToList()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516462/is-there-a-performance-impact-when-calling-tolist) does have a performance impact, it
>   is an *O(n)* operation though it will likely only require attention in
>   performance critical operations.
>
> The `ToList()` operation will use the [`List(IEnumerable<T>
>   collection)`][2] constructor. This constructor must make a copy of the
>   array (more generally `IEnumerable<T>`), otherwise future
>   modifications of the original array will change on the source `T[]`
>   also which wouldn't be desirable generally.

this will answer your second question, whether performance impacts will take place.

Answer (score 0):

One could extend IEnumerable to return a List as follows:

```
public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> gen)
{
    if (gen == null)
    {
        //exception handling here
    }

    return (gen as List<T>) ?? gen.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This isn't about memory allocations. As people said in the comments, this isn't about efficiency. When you use `ToList()` you want and expect a *new* list. You expect that any modifications to it won't affect the original. This method changes that behavior.

Comment: Removed my comment regarding memory allocation.